# Please help me prove this question

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

The Question:
We can define a set of integers $X_a$$_,$$_b$ = {∀u, v ∈ $\Bbb Z$, au + bv}. For example, if a = 6 and b = 8 then X$_6$$_,$$_8$
includes numbers like 20 = 2$*$6 + 1$*$8 and 4 = −2$*$6 + 2$*$8. Let c be the smallest positive integer in
X$_a$$_,$$_b$. Prove that every number in X$_a$$_,$$_b$ is a multiple of c.

Comment: Have you tried by contradiction? If $c$ doesn't divide $m$, then there is a non-zero remainder...

Comment: @ArnaudMortier How does a non-zero remainder have any connection to X$_{a,b}$?

Answer (score 0):

Divide the arbitrary element of $X_{a,b}$ by $c$

The reminder if not zero is a positive number less than $c$ which is also an element of $X_{a,b}$

I let you show that the remainder is indeed an element of $X_{a,b}.$

Comment: How to prove the remainder is an element of X$_{a,b}$? Assume X$_{a,b}$ = k$_1$a + k$_2$b, since k1 and k2 can be anything, does that mean r is an element of X$_{a,b}$

Comment: The remainder is the difference of two elements so it is an element. Think about linear combinations.

Comment: Im sorry but i still dont really understand. What would the two elements be?